# How to make text message clickable with react-native-gifted-chat

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm developing a mobile chat app with `react-native-gifted-chat`, and I would like to make the system messages clickable to execute a function.

My code is below, but somehow it doesn't work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, ImageBackground, Text, Linking, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Body, Container, Header, Icon, Left, Right, Thumbnail } from "native-base";
import { Button, List } from 'react-native-paper';
import { GiftedChat, Composer } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';

export default class ChatScreen extends Component {

  messages = [
    {
      _id: 1,
      text: <Text onClick={() => { alert('hello')}} style={{ color: 'red' }}>This message can not be clickable</Text>,
      createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 5, 11, 17, 20, 0)),
      system: true,
    }
  ];

  renderComposer = props => {
    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Icon type='SimpleLineIcons' name='paper-clip' style={{ fontSize: 20, justifyContent: 'center', paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 5 }}/>
        <Composer {...props} />
        <Button>Submit</Button>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <GiftedChat
          renderComposer={this.renderComposer}
          messages={this.messages}
        />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

});
```

And this is the screenshot of my simulator.
https://gyazo.com/bc1facffffcbe868fbce5cb15385890d

I expect the system message 'This message cannot be clickable' should be clickable and it shows up the alert message 'hello' when clicking it.
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try with **onPress** instead of **onClick** in Text component?

And you can also refer this below.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#onpress

Comment: Your solution works well. It works with onPress. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Text has an onPress props not onClick, So you just need to change onClick to onPress. If you will change this then your *message* will look like this

```
messages = [
    {
      _id: 1,
      text: <Text onPress={() => { alert('hello')}} style={{ color: 'red' }}>This message can not be clickable</Text>,
      createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 5, 11, 17, 20, 0)),
      system: true,
    }
  ];
```

This will definitely work for you!